# Create one query to achieve same result of two

Tags: mysql, sql, join, group-by, having

I want get month list with teachers, expenses and comissions.
Expense contains of installment paid to teacher and price for gived lessons.
Commision is sum of 'commision per lessons' and 'month prices'.

Schema:

```
CREATE TABLE contract
    (`id` int, `teacher` varchar(64), `lesson_price` int, `lesson_price_commision` int, `month_price` int)
;

INSERT INTO contract
    (`id`, `teacher`, `lesson_price`, `lesson_price_commision`, `month_price`)
VALUES
    (1, 'John', 50, 10, 0),
    (2, 'Paul', 40, 15, 0),
    (3, 'Meg', 0, 0, 800)
;

CREATE TABLE installment
    (`id` int, `contract` int, `installment_price` int, `installment_date` date)
;

INSERT INTO installment
    (`id`, `contract`, `installment_price`, `installment_date`)
VALUES
    (1, 1, 300, '2015-09-28'),
    (2, 1, 400, '2015-09-30'),
    (3, 3, 500, '2015-09-28')
;

CREATE TABLE lesson
    (`id` int, `contract` int, `lesson_date` date)
;

INSERT INTO lesson
    (`id`, `contract`, `lesson_date`)
VALUES
    (1, 1, '2015-08-16'),
    (2, 3, '2015-09-01'),
    (3, 2, '2015-09-02'),
    (4, 1, '2015-09-06')
;
```

I made it in two queries, but I must combine them.

Query one:

```
SELECT teacher, SUM(lesson_price_commision) AS commision, SUM(lesson_price) AS expense
FROM contract
JOIN lesson ON contract.id=lesson.contract 
WHERE MONTH(lesson_date) = 9 AND YEAR(lesson_date) = 2015
GROUP BY teacher
```

Query two:

```
SELECT teacher, SUM(month_price) AS commision, SUM(installment_price) AS expense
FROM installment
JOIN contract ON contract.id=installment.contract 
WHERE MONTH(installment_date) = 9 AND YEAR(installment_date) = 2015
GROUP BY teacher
```

I constructed this:

```
SELECT teacher,
       (SUM(lesson_price_commision) + SUM(month_price)) AS commision,
       (SUM(lesson_price)+SUM(installment_price)) AS expense
FROM contract
  JOIN lesson ON contract.id=lesson.contract 
  LEFT JOIN installment ON installment.contract = contract.id
WHERE (MONTH(installment_date) = 9 AND YEAR(installment_date) = 2015)
   OR (MONTH(lesson_date) = 9 AND YEAR(lesson_date) = 2015)
GROUP BY teacher
```

and result is:

```
teacher | comission | expense
-----------------------------
John    |    40     |  1600
Paul    |    15     |  null
Meg     |   800     |   500
```

but I am expecting:

```
teacher | comission | expense
-----------------------------
John    |    10     |  750
Paul    |    15     |   40
Meg     |    800    |  500
```

Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7247a/1

Comment: And the result should be? Please also add all to your question since links can break, especially SQLFiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a very confusing data structure.  I'm not quite sure what the different entities are supposed to represent.  But, the following returns your desired results (see [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7247a/17)):

```
SELECT c.teacher, (c.lesson_price_commision + c.month_price) as commission,
       (c.lesson_price + coalesce(i.expense, 0) ) as expense
FROM contract c LEFT JOIN
     (SELECT c.teacher, sum(installment_price) as expense
      FROM lesson l JOIN
           installment i
           ON i.contract = l.contract join
           contract c
           ON i.contract = c.id
      WHERE l.lesson_date >= '2015-09-01' and  l.lesson_date < '2015-10-01'
      GROUP BY c.teacher
     ) i
     ON c.teacher = i.teacher;
```